# Убрать page=1 из пагинации

Tags: php, pagination

Сделал пагинацию на основе кода нарытого на просторах интернета, так-как такая реализация больше всего мне подходит, помогите сделать так чтобы при переходе на первую страницу переходило не на site.com/category?page=1, а на site.com/category.

Вот оригинал класса:

```
<?php 
/*
* Класс для генерации постраничной навигации
*/
class Pagination
{
    /**
    * 
    * @var Активных ссылок навигации на страницу.
    * Т.е. ссылок, помимо текущей (активной) ссылки и ссылок влево-вправо.
    * 
    */
    private $max = 6;

    /**
    * 
    * @var Ключ для GET, в который пишется номер страницы
    * 
    */
    private $index = 'page';

    /**
    * 
    * @var Текущий GET-запрос
    * 
    */
    private $query;

    /**
    * 
    * @var Текущая страница
    * 
    */
    private $current_page;

    /**
    * 
    * @var Общее количество записей
    * 
    */
    private $total; 

    /**
    * 
    * @var Записей на страницу
    * 
    */
    private $limit;

    /**
    * Запуск необходимых данных для навигации
    * @param integer $total - общее количество записей
    * @param integer $limit - количество записей на страницу
    * 
    * @return
    */
    public function __construct( $total, $limit )
    {
        # Устанавливаем общее количество записей
        $this->total  = $total;

        # Устанавливаем количество записей на страницу
        $this->limit  = $limit;

        # Устанавливаем количество страниц
        $this->amount = $this->amount();

        # Вызываем метод установки текущей страницы
        $this->setCurrentPage();

        # Вызываем метод установки текущего GET-запроса
        $this->setQueryString();
    }

    /**
    *  Для вывода ссылок
    * 
    * @return HTML-код со ссылками навигации
    */
    public function get()
    {
        # Для записи ссылок
        $pagination = null;

        # Получаем ограничения для цикла
        $limits = $this->limits();

        # Генерируем ссылки
        for($page=$limits[0]; $page<=$limits[1]; $page++)
        {
            # Формируем статус ссылки
            $status = $page == $this->current_page ? 'active' : null;

            # Заносим ссылку
            $pagination .= $this->generateHtml($page, null, null, $status);
        }

        # Если текущая страница не первая
        if($this->current_page > 1){
            # Создаём ссылку "Предыдущая"
            $pagination = $this->generateHtml($this->current_page - 1, '<', 'Предыдущая') . $pagination;

            # Создаём ссылку "Первая"
            $pagination = $this->generateHtml(1, '<<', 'Первая') . $pagination;
        }

        # Если текущая страница не первая
        if($this->current_page < $this->amount){
            # Создаём ссылку "Следующая"
            $pagination .= $this->generateHtml($this->current_page + 1, '>', 'Следующая');  

            # Создаём ссылку "Следующая"
            $pagination .= $this->generateHtml($this->amount, '>>', 'Последняя');  
        }

        # Оборачиваем ссылки
        $pagination = '<ul class="pagination">'. $pagination .'</ul>';

        # Возвращаем ссылки
        return $pagination;
    }

    /**
    * Для получения, откуда начинать выборку
    * 
    * @return integer
    */
    public function skip(){
        return 
            $this->current_page * $this->limit - $this->limit;
    }

    /**
    * Для получение ограничения выборки
    * 
    * @return integer
    */
    public function take(){
        # Получаем, откуда начинаем
        $skip = $this->skip();

        # Возвращаем ограницение
        return
            $skip + $this->limit > $this->total ? $this->total - $skip : $this->limit;
    }

    /**
    * Для генерации HTML-кода ссылки
    * @param string $query - текущий GET-запрос
    * @param integer $page - номер страницы
    * 
    * @return
    */
    private function generateHtml( $page, $text=null, $title=null, $status=null ){
        # Если текст ссылки не указан
        if( is_null($text) )
            # Указываем, что текст - цифра страницы
            $text = $page;

        # Формируем ссылку
        $query = $this->index .'='. $page;

        # Формируем строку запроса (после вопроса)
        $query = $this->query ? $this->query .'&'. $query : $query;

        # Формируем статус ссылки
        $status = $status ? 'class="'. $status .'"' : null;

        # Формируем HTML код ссылки и возвращаем
        return 
            '<li '. $status .'><a href="?'. $query .'" title="'. $title .'">'. $text .'</a></li>';
    }

    /**
    *  Для получения, откуда стартовать вывод ссылок
    * 
    * @return массив с началом и концом отсчёта
    */
    private function limits()
    {
        # Вычисляем ссылки слева (чтобы активная ссылка была посередине)
        $left = $this->current_page - round($this->max / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

        # Вычисляем начало отсчёта
        $start = $left > 0 ? $left : 1;               

        # Если впереди есть как минимум $this->max страниц
        if($start + $this->max <= $this->amount)
            # Назначаем конец цикла вперёд на $this->max страниц или просто на минимум
            $end = $start >= 1 ? $start + $this->max : $this->max;
        else{
            # Конец - общее количество страниц
            $end = $this->amount;

            # Начало - минус $this->max от конца
            $start = $this->amount - $this->max > 0 ? $this->amount - $this->max : 1;
        }

        # Возвращаем
        return [$start, $end];
    }

    /**
    * Для установки текущей страницы
    * 
    * @return
    */
    private function setCurrentPage()
    {
        # Получаем номер страницы
        $this->current_page = isset($_GET[$this->index]) ? (int) $_GET[$this->index] : 1;

        # Если текущая страница боле нуля
        if($this->current_page > 0)
        {
            # Если текунщая страница меньше общего количества страниц
            if($this->current_page > $this->amount)
                # Устанавливаем страницу на последнюю
                $this->current_page = $this->amount;
        }
        else
            # Устанавливаем страницу на первую
            $this->current_page = 1;
    }

    /**
    * Для получения и установки текущего GET-запроса
    * 
    * @return
    */
    private function setQueryString(){
        # Получаем параметры текущего запроса
        $query = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY );

        # Разбираем строку запроса
        parse_str( $query, $params );

        # Удаляем значение страницы, если есть
        unset( $params[$this->index] );

        # Формируем запрос
        $this->query = http_build_query( $params );
    }

    /**
    * Для получеия общего числа страниц
    * 
    * @return число страниц
    */
    private function amount()
    {
        # Делим и возвращаем
        return
            ceil( $this->total / $this->limit );
    }
}
```

Comment: Редирект делай при ID=1

Comment: В данный момент так и сделал, но это костыль...

Comment: Это не костыль, а KISS

Comment: @Alex78191, В этом случае нет))) Может что по коду подскажете?)))

Comment: @VadimPedchenko, у вас нужно менять метод generateHtml() с передачей туда не только get-запроса, но и url страницы. Можете конечно попробовать заменить `$query = $this->index .'='. $page;` на `$query = $page > 1 ? $this->index .'='. $page : '';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для первой части вопроса изменим следующую функцию вот таким образом. И если у нас первая страница то в запросе не получим `?page=1`.

```
private function generateHtml( $page, $text=null, $title=null, $status=null ){
    //А это поможет что бы не было первой страницы если она активна
    if(!is_null($status))
       return '';

    # Если текст ссылки не указан
    if( is_null($text) )
        # Указываем, что текст - цифра страницы
        $text = $page;

    # Формируем ссылку
    $query = '';
    if($page > 1){
        $query = $this->index .'='. $page;
    }


    # Формируем строку запроса (после вопроса)
    $query = $this->query ? $this->query .'&'. $query : $query;

    $query = ($page > 1) ? '?'.$query : $this->query;

    # Формируем статус ссылки
    $status = $status ? 'class="'. $status .'"' : null;

    # Формируем HTML код ссылки и возвращаем
    return 
        '<li '. $status .'><a href="'. $query .'" title="'. $title .'">'. $text .'</a></li>';
}
```

Изменил вот эту строку:

```
$query = $this->index .'='. $page;
```

Таким образом:

```
$query = '';
if($page > 1){
    $query = $this->index .'='. $page;
}
```

То есть если страница первая то для запроса `pagination` нечего не ставим.

А это поможет что бы при активной первой странице ее не было видно

```
//А это поможет что бы не было первой страницы если она активна
    if(!is_null($status))
       return '';
```

Comment: `то в запросе не получим ?page=1` - зато получите `?`.

Comment: @Visman А так кажется не получу `?`.

Comment: Угу, и в ссылке у вас будет пусто для первой страницы, и ни куда она не поведет, кроме той же самой страницы на которой сейчас находишься.

Comment: @Visman сейчас кажется `ok`?))))

Comment: Без изменения входных данных (мое первое предложение в комментарии к вопросу) ни какого окея тут быть не может ;)

Comment: @Visman не понял на счет изменения входных данных?

Comment: @Visman То первое предложение к вопросу то же получает `?`.

Comment: Комментарий состоит из двух предложений. В первом я даю рекомендацию о добавлении во входящие данные полной ссылки на страницу. Во втором - даю вариант, который вы написали через 4 минуты в своем ответе (со знаком вопроса в ссылке для первой страницы).

Comment: @Visman ну класс, вы первый

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, Спасибо! Но теперь вообще какая-то каша получилась...

Comment: @VadimPedchenko работает или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо Razmik Galstyan, и Visman, при их помощи удалось устранить недочеты класса, убрать page=1, плюс ко всему избавился от ссылки на активной кнопке. Привожу функцию в которой сделал изменения:

```
    private function generateHtml($page, $text = null, $title = null, $status = null) {
    # Если текст ссылки не указан
    if(is_null($text))
        # Указываем, что текст - цифра страницы
        $text = $page;
    if(!is_null($status)) {
        $query = false;
    }
    else {
        $query = $page > 1 ? $this->index.'/page/'.$page : '';
        $link = 'href="'.$query.'"';
    }

    # Формируем статус ссылки
    $status = $status ? 'class="'.$status.'"' : null;

    # Формируем HTML код ссылки и возвращаем
    return '<li '.$status.'><a '.$link.'  title="'.$title.'">'.$text.'</a></li>';
}
```

Код не финальный, привел это чтобы в контексте было понятно.